# How to turn the file data in to line chart with streamlit

Tags: streamlit

I want to use streamlit's selectbox
to select the height and weight in the file, and then display with line chart on the streamlit.

The x will be the student's name in the file.

The y will be height or weight it can select from the streamlit's selectbox.

The csv file will be like this:

```
Class,Name,Sex,Height,Weight
A01,Canning,F,160,45
A01,Mike,M,172,70
A01,Cena,M,190,80
A01,Nick,M,169,76
A02,Tomy,M,174,65
A02,Ray,F,158,47
A02,Ting,F,172,43
A02,Weng,M,179,68
A03,Jennie,F,156,44
A03,Wex,M,171,82
A03,Jeff,M,166,69
A03,Rudy,M,167,79
```

My py file name will be student_weight.py
Down below is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

st.title("Students information")

stw = pd.read_csv("student_weight.csv")

stw_chart = plt.gca()
st.line_chart(stw_chart,str, x=stw.Height, y=stw.Height, width=500, height=500, use_container_width=True)


contact_options = ["Height","Weight"]
contact_selected = st.selectbox("Select a Students value",
                               options = contact_options)


if contact_selected =="Height":
    plt.plot(stw.Name, stw.Height)
    plt.show()
    st.write("result of Height")
else:
    plt.plot(stw.Name, stw.Weight)
    plt.show()
```

I imagine the result would be something like this:
[image: My imagine]

Answer (score 0):

Even though I found your image misleading, but I guess this work around is what you are looking for.

```py
import streamlit as st
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("student_weight.csv")
st.dataframe(df)

st.title("Students information")

contact_options = ["Height", "Weight"]
contact_selected = st.selectbox("Select a Students value", contact_options)

inform = f"Students {contact_selected} Chart:"
fig = px.line(df, x="Name", y=contact_selected, title=inform)

st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)
```

Output:
[image]